# Python MySQLdb exceptions

Tags: python, mysql, exception

Just starting to get to grips with python and MySQLdb and was wondering

1. Where is the best play to put a try/catch block for the connection to MySQL. At the MySQLdb.connect point? Also should there be one when ever i query?
2. What exceptions should i be catching on any of these blocks?

thanks for any help

Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Catch the MySQLdb.Error, while connecting and while executing query

Answer (score 1):

I think that the connections and the query can raised errors so you should have try/excepy for both of them.