# How to check if table in databse exist and how to display error?

Tags: python

How to check if the table in database exist before creating it by using Python?

**I would like to check if it exist then drop the table. If not, then create..**

Also, how to display error if there are some errors in the codes of database?

(If in PHP. Codes will be die("....."); for Error Handling.. So what should I use in Python?)

Any advice?

Comment: What kind of database / what adapter are you using?

Comment: MySQLdb..If you meant database module.

Comment: @ThanaDaray, and what python module are you using to access MySQL?

Comment: import MySQLdb. I used this one to access...

Answer (score 2):

From the [MySQL manal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) use

```
CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS ...
```

To create a table if it doesn't exist.  That might even be standard SQL (not sure but it will work in sqlite too)!

As for your second question "how to display error if there are some errors in the codes of database?" not sure exactly what you mean. but if MySQL returns an error then the database module will turn it into a python exception - see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117828/python-mysqldb-exceptions) for some discussion

Comment: if in PHP. Codes will be die("File not found"); for Error Handling.. So what should I use in Python?

Comment: Based on the linked question: `try: whatever database code;    except MySQLdb.Error: print "error"`